# PDO Exception: The server requested authentication method unknown to the client

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a running LARAVEL based website on a shared hosting (Business Plan) with Hostgator India. Ee decided to migrate it to a recently purchased dedicated server. The content transfer/migration was successful, however, when I try to LOGIN/REGISTER using the default laravel methods on the dedicated server I get following exception:

```
PDO Exception: The server requested authentication method unknown to the client
```

After, researching a lot on Google / StackOverflow I discovered that there could be a mismatch in the server mysql version. However, I am not able to understand how to get it fixed. I am currently using a PHP 5.5 (Also tried PHP 5.4 with no success). Downgrading it to PHP 5.3 would work, with its own sweet problems for "syntax errors" and requires quite a lot of the change in the code. The code works absolutely fine on the business plan and my local MAMP server. I am sure I am missing something very small here and would be really thankful if someone could point me in right direction.

Edit 1: MySql information on Server

Server type: MySQL

Server version: 5.5.37-cll - MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Comment: So, what's the MySQL version on your dedicated server?

Comment: Ah, forgot to add that. Just added to the question.

Comment: Have you followed [these steps](http://forumsarchive.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=8667)? If yes, which exactly? If not, can you try the OLD_PASSWORD update one?

Comment: I actually tried to downgrade and then upgrade with no success. Let me try this and keep the post updated. Give me few minutes.

Comment: Seriously, I can't believe this. It is working now. However, still an open question is that, what upgrade version is required to get it working?

Comment: Just to confirm, you downgraded PHP then upgraded it back to 5.5 and it works? How did you do the downgrade / upgrade? Did you build PHP from source or you installed a package? Or what happened was that you just updated the MySQL user's password with `OLD_PASSWORD` function?

Comment: I tried multiple things, a.) Downgraded to php 5.3(because of PDO exception) from 5.4 provided by dedicated, however, that results in a compilation error for multiple packages (maatwebsite/excel, way/generators). b.) I upgraded the to php 5.5 and then also upgraded mysql to topmost version via Easy Apache (WHM), however, same error and lastly what worked was I created a new mysql user by commenting and un-commenting OLD_PASSWORDS as suggested in your answer and finally that worked. However, I am not sure whether the commenting was really required.

Comment: The uncomment was needed so that the `OLD_PASSWORD` function works.  Then, you comment it back to disable that password digest algorithm so that any new users added to MySQL would work as expected. Anyway, I'm glad you got it fixed :)